# Entity Framework - group multiple foreign keys into a single column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

New to EF here and having some difficulty.

I have about 24 tables I need to create with code-first.  Each one of these tables has around 2 - 10 many-to-one relationships that are simple and can be represented with 1 table.  Here are just a few of my classes to illustrate my structure...

```
namespace EMRS
{
    public class ERecord
    {
        [Key]
        public int PCRId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<EFirstClass> EFirstClass {get; set;}
        public virtual List<ESecondClass> ESecondClass { get; set; }
    }

    public class EFirstElement
    {
        [Key]
        public int ElementId { get; set; } 
        public ElementCode stuff1 { get; set; } //eAirway.06
        public string stuff2 { get; set; } 

        public int PCRId { get; set; }
        public virtual ERecord EReportId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SubElement> Stuff4List { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<SubElement> Stuff5List { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<SubElement> Stuff6List { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<SubElement> Stuff7List { get; set; }

}

    public class ESecondElement
    {
        [Key]
        public int ElementId { get; set; }

        public ElementCode Stuff9 { get; set; }   
        public ElementCode Stuff10 { get; set; }

        public int PCRId { get; set; }
        public virtual ERecord EReportId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList11 { get; set; }  
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList12 { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList13 { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList14 { get; set; }  
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList15 { get; set; }   
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList16 { get; set; } 
        public virtual List<SubElement> StuffList17 { get; set; } 
}

    public class SubElement
    {
        public int SubElementId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public dynamic Type { get; set; }
        public int ElementId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I were to create a class/table for each individual 1 to many relationship in the element classes, I would end up with many tables with exactly the same structure.  What I would like to do would be to have a foreign key in the SubElement class that references more than 1 class.

I tried having a parentelement abstract class and inheriting it in all of my element classes but EF created a table for that class(Parentelement) and placed all columns in all Element classes within that table.

Is there any way to do this with EF Code first?

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment, but if you have the ability, create the tables in the DB that you'd like and then generate models from it to see how EF creates them.

Comment: Looks like you should add a type to the element table and all can be in one collection.